# What is the sum of 1/n^n as n goes to infinity?

Tags: summation

What is the actual value of the sum of 1/n^n as n goes to infinity? It's about 1.29129.

Comment: In my sincere opinion, as far as I know, the exact value of this sum is unknown

Comment: imranfat +1 In my school years I calculated such sums, but did not find anything interesting. So I am not Srinivasa Ramanujan. :-)